# In google cloudSQL can I configure it with my.cnf

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-compute-engine

In a similar way I can include a php.ini in app engine projects 
is there a way to configure cloudSQL instances by providing a my.cnf or do I need to submit the SQL equivalent?

Do values set that way apply to new instances of the same db when responding to demand?

Comment: Doesn't appear so, this issue is asking for something similar from 2013 http://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=68 and if you connect MySQL Client and try set global @@variable =value; it returns msg to say its read-only

Comment: Not yet. In the meantime, please email cloud-sql@google.com with your instance name and the parameters that you'd like to set.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that was an option

Comment: Did you find a way to configure your SQL server on Google CloudSQL?

Comment: @probitaille sorry it isn't something I continued but maybe the answer below will be of use

Comment: I tried. The flags of Cloud SQL are limited. You can't configure every parameters.

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to set up [MySQL flags using Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/mysql-flags).